# wxPython, using SplitterWindow

Tags: wxpython

I'd like to put TreeCtrl on both side of SplitterWindow. And, of course, TreeCtrl should be **expanded** as window's size.

```
splitter  = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_BORDER)

leftPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)
rightPanel  = wx.Panel(splitter)

leftSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
rightSizer  = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

localTree = wx.TreeCtrl(leftPanel)
flickrTree  = wx.TreeCtrl(rightPanel)

leftSizer.Add(localTree, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
rightSizer.Add(flickrTree, flag = wx.EXPAND)

splitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, rightPanel)
leftPanel.SetSizer(leftSizer)
leftPanel.SetAutoLayout(1)
leftSizer.Fit(leftPanel)
```

I've tried above code, but TreeCtrl's height is not expanded as I expected.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_BORDER)
leftPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)
rightPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)

localTree = wx.TreeCtrl(leftPanel)
leftSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
leftSizer.Add(localTree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
leftPanel.SetSizer(leftSizer)

flickrTree  = wx.TreeCtrl(rightPanel)
rightSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
rightSizer.Add(flickrTree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
rightPanel.SetSizer(rightSizer)

splitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, rightPanel)
```

The key thing is to set the proportion value when adding the TreeCtrl to the BoxSizer, i.e:

leftSizer.Add(localTree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

rather than:

leftSizer.Add(localTree, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

Otherwise, it defaults to zero.